# Unity 2D same state for different enemies issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making 2D platformer and im getting weird bug - when i hit one enemy, every one else of that type getting the same state. I mean i wanted them to enter "angry" state when my player hit one of them with sword.

*Problem looks like this:*

->Hit Enemy1 with sword,

->Enemy1 is getting damage and going to "angry" state,

->Enemy2/3/4/5 didn't get damage, but went in "angry" state.

If getting damage is individual for every one of them so why am i suffer that kind of situation. I think the cause is in my Damage Script. If anyone have an idea i would be glad to hear it. Thanks in advance.

```
public void DealDmg()
{
    blob = FindObjectOfType<EnemyScript>();

    if (attackPos.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {

        Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos.position, attackRange, whatIsEnemy);

        for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
        {
            EnemyScript enemyScript = enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<EnemyScript>();

            enemyScript.GetComponent<EnemyScript>().TakeDmg(damage);

            if (gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControls>().facingRight == true)
            {
                enemyScript.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(30f, 20f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                StartCoroutine("ResetValues");

                blob.CalmLogic();

            }
            else if (gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControls>().facingRight == false)
            {
                enemyScript.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(-30f, 20f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                StartCoroutine("ResetValues");

                blob.CalmLogic();

            }
        }
        attackPos.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
    public IEnumerator ResetValues()
{
    gotHit = true;
    blob.gotAngry = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(resetValuesDelay);
    gotHit = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(resetValuesDelay);
    blob.gotAngry = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Track enemy state *inside the enemy*

Right now it looks like your code is running on the player and the *player* is keeping track of enemy state. This is wrong. Your player script should never know anything about (much less modify!) the properties of your enemy. All the player should do is:

- when the player successfully hits an enemy, the player tells the enemy "you've been hit!"
- The enemy script then takes that information (such as how much damage, what damage type it was, etc) and deal with itself: reducing the damage ("am I wearing armor?"), enhancing the damage ("am I weak to fire?") and so on and so forth...like getting angry at the player and the resulting cooldown before its calm again.

Your player script does not need to know (and does not care!) about this information and any attempt to try and handle it here is folly. As soon as you change how many enemies there are, or create a new enemy type that does something ELSE you end up with a giant pile of useless junk you can't manage.

Comment: Thanks, good practices are generally good - so i did like u say and removed every thing what were linking this two scrips. I managed with it by checking if enemy lost health if so, then state is active. To be honest now its working more naturally. Thank you - again :)